Aggregated column's with conditions in pandas
Does anyone know how to create an aggregated column with conditions in pandas?
I need the same logic as in this SQL code:
SELECT day, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN category = "A" THEN sales ELSE NULL END) / SUM(sales) * 100 AS output_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN category = "B" AND sex = "female" THEN sales ELSE NULL END) / SUM(sales) * 100 AS output_2
FROM table
GROUP BY 1

Source table:
         day category     sex  sales
0     Monday        A    male    100
1    Tuesday        B  female    200
2  Wednesday        C    male    150
3   Thursday        A  female    180
4     Friday        B    male    220
5   Saturday        C  female    120
6     Sunday        A    male    140
7     Monday        B  female    160

Sample output:
      day   output_1    output_2
0   Monday  10          20
1  Tuesday  40          50
2   Sunday  25          35

I believe there's approach how to put this conditional-aggregated column's inside .agg() method, but can't find a proper solution.
result = (
    df.groupby('column_1')
    .agg(
        output_1(),
        output_2()
    )
    .reset_index()
)


Are you sure the expected output is connected to the sample data?

Please add output that contains the values that you actually expect based on the input sample. E.g. for day == 'Monday', shouldn't output1 be: 100/(100+160)*100 -> 38.46? And so on.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Here you have a solution.
First define your data in a df:
data = {
        'day': ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday', 'Monday'],
        'category': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B'],
        'sex': ['male', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'female', 'male', 'female'],
        'sales': [100, 200, 150, 180, 220, 120, 140, 160]
    }
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

Then you can use groupby and pivot methods to get to your solution:
Take into account that here we are grouping by day and category, and pivoting 'category' to columns
df = df.groupby(['day','category']).agg(sales=('sales','sum')).reset_index()
df = df.pivot(index=['day'], columns=['category'],values='sales').reset_index()
df


